# Implement two interfaces in an anonymous class

Tags: java, android

I have two interfaces:

```
interface A {
    void foo();
}

interface B {
    void bar();
}
```

I am able to create anonymous instances of classes implementing either of these interfaces like so:

```
new A() {
    void foo() {}
}
```

or:

```
new B() {
    void bar() {}
}
```

I want to create an anonymous class that implements both interfaces. Something like (the fictitious):

```
new A implements B {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}
```

This obviously gives a compile error: "B cannot be resolved to a type".

The workaround is quite simple:

```
class Aggregate implements A, B {
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}
```

I then use `Aggregate` where ever I would have used the anonymous class.

I was wondering if it is even legal for an anonymous class to implement two interfaces.

Comment: See [why-an-anonymous-class-cant-implement-multiple-interfaces-directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774168/why-an-anonymous-class-cant-implement-multiple-interfaces-directly)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

"An anonymous inner class can extend one subclass or implement one
interface. Unlike non-anonymous classes (inner or otherwise), an anonymous
inner class cannot do both. In other words, it cannot both extend a class and
implement an interface, nor can it implement more than one interface. " (http://scjp.wikidot.com/nested-classes)

Answer (score 25):

If you are determined to do this, you could declare a third interface, C:

```
public interface C extends A, B {
}
```

In this way, you can declare a single anonymous inner class, which is an implementation of C.

A complete example might look like:

```
public class MyClass {

  public interface A {
    void foo();
  }

  public interface B {
    void bar();
  }

  public interface C extends A, B {
    void baz();
  }

  public void doIt(C c) {
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
    c.baz();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();

    mc.doIt(new C() {
      @Override
      public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo()");
      }

      @Override
      public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar()");
      }

      @Override
      public void baz() {
        System.out.println("baz()");
      }
    });
  }

}
```

The output of this example is:

```
foo()
bar()
baz()
```

Answer (score 7):

For save some keystrokes (for example if the interfaces have a lot of methods) you can do this:

```
abstract class Aggregate implements A, B {
}

new MyObject extends Aggregate {
   void foo() {}
   void bar() {}
}
```

Notice the key is to declare the `Aggregate` as abstract.

Comment: Another alternative is to make Aggregate an interface itself: `interface Aggregate extends A, B {}`.

Comment: in what language this compiles?

Comment: In Java, for example?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can make a named *local* class that implements the two interfaces:

```
void method() {
    class Aggregate implements A, B {
        void foo() {}
        void bar() {}
    }

    A a = new Aggregate();
    B b = new Aggregate();
}
```

This save you from doing a class-level or top-level class declaration.

The result is called a [*local class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html). Local classes declared in instance methods are also inner classes, which means that they can reference the containing object instance.