# Why Java anonymous classes couldn't implement more than one interface?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WHY an Anonymous class in Java can't implement multiple interfaces directly? Simply because of syntax or there is another reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774168/why-an-anonymous-class-in-java-cant-implement-multiple-interfaces-directly-sim)

Hi all I was wondering why is it that Java anonymous classes couldn't implement more than one interface?

Like what problems will we have if the Java designers allowed anonymous classes to implement more than one interface?

As such:

```
IMammal, I4legged anonymous_creature = new IMammal, I4legged() {
    {
        //..
    }
};
anonymous_creature.FourLeggedStuff();
anonymous_creature.MammalStuff();
```

Comment: @CodeBrickie that's a duplicate of my thread ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Like what problems will we have if the Java designers allowed anonymous classes to implement more than one interface?*

In Javas type-system there is precisely one static type for each expression. If you had to choose *one* static type for `anonymous_creature` you wouldn't be able to make much use of the variable, which is probably why you wrote

```
IMammal, I4legged anonymous_creature =
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which actually changes Javas type-system fundamentally. (Possibly it has been excluded for the same reason as multiple inheritance, namely in order to keep the language simple.)

Besides, there is a trivial workaround, and that is to introduce a auxiliary interface extending both of them:

```
interface FourLeggedMammal extends IMammal, I4Legged {
}
```

and then do

```
... new FourLeggedMammal() { ... }
```

Comment: I guess an "Ambigious method call" compile-time error would happen.

Comment: This might be true with the example the OP gave, but why not allow `Mammal c = new Mammal() implements I4Legged { //I4Leged implementations... }`. I've needed this more than once, and had to go the trivial-workaround-way

Comment: @XaviLópez, but what use would that be? `c` couldn't be used as a `I4Legged` anyway, right?

Comment: Why not? It could be just a tagging interface. Maybe I'd like to implement a `Restricted` tagging interface, so that a UI component is marked as restricted. I've needed to do something similar to this, don't remember exactly if with interfaces or annotations.

Comment: @aioobe I think he meant `I4Leg` c = new Mammal() implements I4Leg {..` which in this case it could have been used as an `I4Leg`

Comment: But then it couldn't for instance be passed to a method that accepts a `Mammal`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can via an `abstract` class:

```
public abstract class AFourLeggedMammal implements IMammal, I4legged {
}
```

then in your code, you can do:

```
AFourLeggedMammal dog = new AFourLeggedMammal() {

}

dog.FourLeggedStuff();
dog.MammalStuff();
```

Comment: ...obviously. But then it wouldn't be an anonymous class anymore, so this is kind of different.

Comment: Well you just changed your answer to the same thing only with an interface. The class in the end is also `anonymous` as the name of the class for `dog` is compiler generated. That's all `anonymous` means.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any technical problem. But anonymous inner classes should be small. Typically implementing a single method. If you want to implement more then a single interface you are probably better of with a top level class.

Of course if you absolutely have to you can create an interface that combines all the interfaces you want to implement and then create an anonymous class for that. Of course the new interface needs a name ...

Answer (score 0):

http://books.google.it/books?id=G4ridwFSpIoC&pg=PA472&lpg=PA472#v=onepage&q&f=false
Paragraph that starts with "One more thing...".

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous class can only implement one interface. Why? It's simply a language design choice. Nothing would make it technically impossible.

If you want to implement two or more interfaces you will have to make it a named class or use an intermediate interface or abstract class which extends  (interface) or implements (abstract class) two or more other interfaces. Also, you can only refer to it only by one interface name, not two, just like all other objects in Java.

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but author asked about 'why?' it can only implement one interface. What is the reason behind that?

Comment: OK, explained why. Maybe you can now remove your downvote?