# What is the type of an intersected type?

Tags: java, java-8

Consider the following code which uses the ability to intersect types, which was added in Java 8:

```
private <E, T extends List<E> & RandomAccess> void takeList(T list) {

}

private void fakingRandomAccess() {
    List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    takeList((List<Integer> & RandomAccess)linkedList);
}
```

I have made a `takeList` method that only takes lists that have (near) constant access times, for whatever reason, but I can imagine that there would be situations where it is indeed warranted to do it such.

Passing an `ArrayList<E>` into the method should work just fine, however via type intersections you can also pass in a `LinkedList<E>` by pretending that it has constant access time.

Now my questions are:

- Is there any way to store `(List<Integer> & RandomAccess)linkedList` in an object of a specified type?
- Can I use type intersections to simplify the `takeList` method?

Comment: How would you want `takeList` method to be simplified? Do you want to avoid that cast? Why do you want to pass an argument that doesn't satisfy the bounds?

Comment: @RohitJain I was thinking about `private <E> void takeList(List<E> & RandomAccess list)`, but that syntax (obviously?) doesn't work.

Comment: Certainly that is not valid syntax of course. But even if it was allowed, I hardly see that as a simplification.

Comment: To be clear, `private <E, T extends List<E> & RandomAccess> void takeList(T list)` has worked ever since Java 6 at least. However, `takeList((List<Integer> & RandomAccess)linkedList);` only works in Java 8.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Your statements are true regarding the syntax, but in Java 8 the latter fragment (which comes from skiwi's code) will compile but will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`. This is because the cast still does a runtime check, and `LinkedList` does not in fact implement `RandomAccess`. So there's no way to fake it this way.

Comment: @StuartMarks What is the difference versus this code then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda (The answer), it seems to use a similar mechanism.

Comment: @skiwi The rules for an AIC are quite limited; see [JLS 15.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1). For `new T() { ... }` if T is a class, the AIC is a direct subclass of T, and if T is an interface, the AIC is a subclass of `Object` that implements T. That's it. For lambdas, the class of the resulting instance takes into account the target type, including iterfaces mentioned in intersection types. See [JLS 15.27.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4). So lambdas are treated quite differently than AICs in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing two different things up.

In the [How to serialize a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda) question & answer there is a *lambda expression* being cast to an intersection type.

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable)() -> System.out.println("Serializable!");
```

This tells the compiler to *generate* a type compatible to the intersection type. Therefore the generated class for the lambda expression will be both, `Runnable` and `Serializable`.

---

Here you are casting an instance of a concrete class to an intersection type:

```
(List<Integer> & RandomAccess)linkedList
```

This requests a runtime-*check* whether the concrete instance’s class implements an appropriate type, i.e. fulfills all interfaces. This runtime-check fails as `LinkedList` does not implement `RandomAccess`.

Comment: And `List<Integer> linkedList = (List<Integer> & RandomAccess)new LinkedList<Integer>()` also makes no sense, I suppose?

Comment: That’s right. And I think, an IDE should tell you that in a Warning.

Comment: Interestingly enough it does warn me if I use `new LinkedList<Integer>()`, and gives an error if I use `new LinkedList<>()` in Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: But does it behave differently for `ArrayList`? I guess, it’s more like type-casts do not work together with the “diamond operator”.