# bitwise and between Comparator and Serializable in Comparator.comparing

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I am looking at the source code of the `Comparator.comparing` method implemented in Java8

here is the code

```
public static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
        Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyComparator);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyComparator.compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
                                          keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Why the bit-wise `and` between `Comparator` and `Serializable` is required and what it does?

```
(Comparator<T> & Serializable)
```

It can be simply casted to `Comparator` for chaining.

also how does bit-wise operations works in case of non numeric values?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819804/what-is-the-type-of-an-intersected-type

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374083/whats-the-meaning-of-the-character-in-the-returned-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bitwise operation between types but an *intersection type*, indicating to the compiler that, when it generates the type corresponding to the lambda expression, this type should implement both `Comparator` and `Serializable` interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The single & is not a bitwise operator in this case. It is an intersection of types Comparator AND Serializable. You are asserting that you want the return type to implement both Comparator and Serializable. The trick here is that you can take the intersection of interfaces as long as the intersection results in only a single abstract method. See 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16

The bitwise operators (&, ^, |) may be used to compare booleans and numeric types, but that is not what is happening here. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22