# What is more idiomatic: setters taking an Optional<T> or just T?

Tags: java, guava

When using `Optional<T>` with a nullable field, is it more idiomatic to have the setter take

- an `Optional<T>` 
  or
- just a `T` and then have it as follows?

```java
public class Bar {
    private Optional<T> foo;

    public void setFoo(T foo) {
        this.foo = Optional.<T>fromNullable(foo);
    }

    public Optional<T> getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, it depends... What do you want `.getFoo()` to return?

Comment: That's also open an question, but right now `.getFoo()` is returning an `Optional<T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd consider doing neither and store the value internally as just T and only have the Optional at the API level.

```
public class Bar {
    private T foo;

    public Optional<T> getFoo() {
        return Optional.<T>fromNullable(foo);
    }

    public void setFoo(T foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: My only comment is it might be more idiomatic to do `this.foo = Preconditions.checkNotNull(foo)`, and have a separate `clearFoo()` method.  You could additionally have `setFoo(Optional<T> foo)` which does `this.foo = foo.orNull()`.

Comment: Are there any benefits to storing it just as T or it just Smells Better?

Comment: @SauloSilva Some benefits are discussed (in the context of Java 8's `Optional<T>` which is similar) in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24564612/502399).

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, I'd suggest:

```
public void setFoo(T foo) {
  this.foo = checkNotNull(foo); // don't allow null at all!
}
```

Then, *if* a user has a value that they know may be `null`, they can do:

```
if (foo != null) {
  bar.setFoo(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latter would be my suggestion. But it is objective as to which is more idiomatic.

```
public class Bar {
    private T foo;

    public void setFoo(T foo) {
        this.foo = Optional.<T>fromNullable(foo);
    }
}
```