# Jackson does not convert nested Java 8 Optional from Javers Change object, what is special about it?

Tags: json, groovy, jackson, javers

I am trying to send a list of Javers Changes as JSON via a REST api. While Jackson can handle Java 8 Optionals via loading the respective module it fails to serialize the Change object. When i create a class with Optionals myself the serialization works as expected.

To reproduce one can run the following groovy script:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module
import org.javers.core.JaversBuilder
import org.javers.repository.jql.QueryBuilder

@Grapes([
  @Grab("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.3"),
  @Grab(group='com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', module='jackson-datatype-jdk8', version='2.8.3'),
  @Grab('org.javers:javers-core:2.3.0')]
)

class Test {
  def bar
  def baz

  Test(){
    baz = "baz"
    bar = "bar"
  }
}

def test = new Test()

def javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build()

javers.commit("user", test)

test.bar = "foo"

javers.commit("user", test)

def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module())

println objectMapper.writeValueAsString(javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().build()))
```

This outputs:

```
[
  {
    "commitMetadata": {
      "empty": false,
      "present": true
    },
    "propertyName": "bar",
    "left": "bar",
    "right": "foo",
    "affectedGlobalId": {
      "typeName": "Test"
    },
    "affectedLocalId": null,
    "affectedObject": {
      "empty": true,
      "present": false
    }
  }
]
```

A custom class gets serialzed as expected:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module

@Grapes([
        @Grab("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.3"),
        @Grab(group='com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', module='jackson-datatype-jdk8', version='2.8.3')]
)

class Test2 {
  def bar
  def baz
  Test2(){
    baz = Optional.of("baz")
    bar = "bar"
  }
}

def test = new Test2()

def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module())

println objectMapper.writeValueAsString(test)
```

Output:

```
{
  "bar": "bar",
  "baz": "baz"
}
```

What is special about the Javers Change class, that Jackson refuses to serialze the Optionals?

Comment: You shouldn't have Optionals as Fields in your class

Comment: Seems reasonable, but could you elaborate on why one shouldn't do this?

Comment: To answer my question: Optionals are not serializable and were not intended to be used as class variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033935/4180338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson doesn't know Javers' Optionals and tries to serialize them as a standard Java Bean which is wrong in this case.
You can fix it by writing a custom serializer for Jackson.

Javers' Optionals exists because replacing them with Java8 Optionals would
brake Java7 clients.

Comment: Actually i didn't realize that the Javers Optionals are not Java Optionals... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem again and remembered my question here. In case someone needs a solution. Here is a custom Jackson Serializer for the Javers Optional:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.javers.common.collections.Optional;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class JaversOptionalSerializer extends StdSerializer<Optional> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8330773428393250826L;

  public JaversOptionalSerializer() {
    super(Optional.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(final Optional value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    if(value.isPresent()){
      JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = provider.findValueSerializer(value.get().getClass());
      serializer.serialize(value.get(), gen, provider);
    } else {
      gen.writeNull();
    }
  }
}
```