# Should I use java.util.Optional as class field?

Tags: java, option-type

java.util.Optional class helps prevent **null pointer exceptions** when used as a method return type instead of returning 'raw' objects (those may be **null**, potentially resulting in NPE).

However, what about other uses? Is it a good idea to use Optional as object field(s) type? Static class fields? 
I.e.,

```
class MyClass {
    private Optional<String> myValue; // does it look reasonable?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just wrap it every time you use `myValue`?

Comment: You can look for your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033518/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-optional-as-an-attribute-in-a-class