# How to interpret and use Java 1.8 Optional Class

Tags: java

This is a code segment from another StackOverflow question:

```
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID entityValue) {
    return ofNullable(entityValue).map(entityUuid -> entityUuid.toString()).orElse(null);
}
```

I am really struggling to understand the use of the Optional class.  Is the return code saying "return the value of the map (a String) or NULL if that fails?

How can return be acting on a method rather than a Class - that is Optional.ofNullable()?

Comment: "_How can return be acting on a method rather than a Class_" - `return` doesn't act on "methods" or "classes" - it acts on **expressions**. `return getStuff()` is perfectly valid if `getStuff()` itself returns an approriate value. `return calculateStuff(10).toString()` is perfectly valid if the method returns a `String`.

Comment: Don't use `Optional` like that, I know the (maybe only) situation  suitable for `Optional` is as the return value of a method to indicate the client to handle the null

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go step by step:

```
ofNullable(entityValue)
```

creates an Optional of the incoming parameter (which is allowed to be null, using `of()` a NPE gets thrown for null input)

```
.map(entityUuid -> entityUuid.toString())
```

Then you pick the actual value, and invoke `toString()` on that value ... which only happens if `entityValue` isn't null. If it is null, the result comes from  `orElse(null)`.

In the end, the result of that operation on the Optional is returned as result of the method.

The above code is nothing but a glorified version of

```
if (entityValue == null) return null;
return entityValue.toString();
```

Optionals have their place in Java, but your example isn't a good one.

It doesn't help readability a bit, and you are not alone with wondering "what is going on here".

Comment: I would add another point for the Russian Blue - if I could :)   maybe British shorthair - hard to tell

Answer (score 8):

This is a really bad use of `Optional`. In fact the [java developers themself say that optional should not be used in such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/5515060), but only as a return argument from a method. More can be read in this great answer: [Is it good practice to use optional as an attribute in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033935/5515060)

The code can be rewritten to this:

```
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID entityValue) {
    return entityValue == null ? null : entityValue.toString();
}
```

Comment: Or `Objects.toString(entityValue)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that will return `"null"` rather than `null`. Which may be unexpected

Answer (score 3):

> Is the return code saying "return the value of the map (a String) or NULL if that fails?

Yes. You can check the documentation of `Optional` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). It tells you exactly what `map` and `orElse` do.

> How can return be acting on a method rather than a Class - that is Optional.ofNullable()?

You are not returning the method. You are returning the return value of a method. Look at this simple example:

```
int myMethod() {
    return foo();
}

int foo() { return 10; }
```

See? I am not returning `foo` the method, I am returning `10`, the return value of `foo`.

<sub>Note that it is possible to return methods, with functional interfaces.</sub>

In this case, you are returning the return value of the last method in the method chain, `orElse`. `ofNullable` creates an `Optional<T>`, then `map` is called on this object and returns a new `Optional<T>`, then `orElse` is called and *its* return value is returned.

Comment: `Note that it is possible to return methods, with functional interfaces` -> not really, no. Only in the syntax sense - what is returned is not a "method".

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's what I mean, yes. I just want to make it as easy as possible for what seems like a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be turn like this :

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID entityValue) {
    if(entityValue==null){
        return null;
    }else{
        return entityValue.toString();
    }
}
```

Your initial code have two statements:
Optional.ofNullable(entityValue): create an Optional Object to say the value can be present or not.
.map(entityUuid -> entityUuid.toString()).orElse(null); you apply some operation to your Optional object, return a string of it or null.

This will avoid a null pointer exception in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

**Optional.ofNullable(T value):**

Returns an Optional describing the specified value, if non-null, otherwise returns an empty Optional.

**Optional.orElse(null)**

Return the value if present, otherwise return null.

Follow [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)