# How to make a field optional?

Tags: java, option-type

I have a class like so

```java
class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  ...
}
```

I want the `lastName` property to be **optional**. How do I accomplish this in Java?

In some languages it's quite elegant and simple wherein we just append a *question mark* after the field name.

Comment: There is no concept for this in Java. Most people would just assign `null` to it and return `Optional<String>` on methods that would return it. (It is usually not recommended to store the thing as `Optional<String>`, nor to take such arguments, only to return it).

Comment: You've already achieved it. All reference types are nullable.

Comment: What do you mean by optional ? It's already kind of optional since you decide if you assign a value to your attribute or not.

Comment: In languages like Kotlin, a `String` is non-nullable whereas a `String?` is nullable. In Java, all Strings are nullable and therefore you can treat all Strings as optional. Now your question should be: how to make them non-optional. That's a tricky one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overview

There is **no language concept** for this in Java.

In Java, all (non-primitive) types are **nullable**, hence can be seen *optional*. So you could just assign it `null` and call it a day.

To overcome the problems related with that, make intention clearer and strive for **fail-fast**, what I have seen being used a lot would be to assign `null` to it internally and return `Optional<String>` on methods that would return it, such as a `getLastName()` method.

---

### Code example

So one way doing this could be:

```java
class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  User(@NotNull String firstName) {
     this(firstName, null);
  }

  User(@NotNull String firstName, @Nullable String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  @NotNull Optional<String> getLastName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(lastName);
  }

  void setLastName(@Nullable String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  ...
}
```

I used the `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` annotations intentionally to make it clearer for you where `null` could be allowed in such a design.

Note that if you have more optional parameters, a **builder-pattern** might also become handy.

Ultimately, also think about whether having optional values is a good design in the first place - maybe you can **redesign** the entire thing on a bigger picture to aovid the situation all together.

---

### Optional as field or argument

Note that it is usually **not recommended** to store the field as `Optional<String>`, nor to take such arguments, for example a `setLastName(Optional<String>)`.

`Optional` was designed only to be used by methods wo want to indicate the lack of a return value.

You can read more about that here:

- [Is it a good practice to use Optional as an attribute in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033518/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-optional-as-an-attribute-in-a-class)
- [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional)

Answer (score 1):

Just assign null to it, when you call it.
you can also just assign it a empty string and then if needed for your use case have a method that checks if it is empty and from there knows that that particular user only has a first name
`user("John","")`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Optional` monad. Though honestly, I'd just keep the values as-is, and treat the fact that they are nullable elsewhere (depends on the case):

```
Optional.ofNullable(user.getFirstName()).orElse("unknown");

Optional.ofNullable(user.getFirstName()).orElseThrow(() 
    -> new InvalidArgumentException("First name is required);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create a getter that returns `Optional`:

```
class User {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public Optional<String> getLastName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(lastName);
  }
}
```

and then:

```
User user = new User();
...
String lastName = user.getFirstName();
Optional<String> lastName = user.getLastName();
```