# jackson does not read back data from json when fields are Optional

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, option-type

I am using `Java 8` to perform this task. I also following dependency work with `JDK8` datatypes.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have a class that looks like

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Optional<Address> address;
    private Optional<String> phone;

    private Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this(firstName, lastName, age, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age,
                  Optional<Address> address, Optional<String> phone) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<String> getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private Address getAddressForJson(){
        return address.orElse(null);
    }

    @JsonProperty("phone")
    private String getPhoneForJson() {
        return phone.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zip;
    private String country;

    public Address(String street, String city, String state, int zip, String country) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public int getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
}
```

I write a test to write a valid `Person` object to a file and and read it back to a `Person` object. My test is

```
@Test
    public void writeAndReadPersonAsJsonOnFile() throws Exception {
        Address address = new Address("1 Infinite Loop", "Cupertino", "CA", 95014, "USA");
        String phone = "1-800-My-Apple";
        Person person = new Person("john", "doe", 21, Optional.of(address), Optional.of(phone));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = registerJdkModuleAndGetMapper();
        File file = temporaryFolder.newFile("person.json");
        objectMapper.writeValue(file, person);

        assertTrue(file.exists());
        assertTrue(file.length() > 0);

        Person personFromFile = objectMapper.readValue(file, Person.class);
        assertEquals(person, personFromFile);

    }

    private ObjectMapper registerJdkModuleAndGetMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

The `file` created as part of test has following contents

```
{
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 21,
    "address": {
        "street": "1 Infinite Loop",
        "city": "Cupertino",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": 95014,
        "country": "USA"
    },
    "phone": "1-800-My-Apple"
}
```

But when reading back, I get `personFromFile` which looks like following

```
personFromFile = {Person@1178} 
 firstName = "john"
 lastName = "doe"
 age = 21
 address = null
 phone = null
```

as you can see, the `address` and `phone` they both are null, even though they are present in the file.

What is wrong here?

**UPDATE**
The codebase is https://github.com/101bits/java8-optional-json. This also contains the failing test

Comment: Your example fails for me because of a missing constructor in `Address`. Are you sure you have full code here?

Comment: I just added the link to codebase, also tried what you said, but it does not work

Comment: It's probably using the 3-arg constructor. Try marking your constructor with `@JsonCreator`.

Comment: Can you please post the failure you're getting from JUnit?

Comment: The real issue here is the `@JsonIgnore`. Get rid of it, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marking one of the constructors with @JsonCreator to tell Jackson which constructor to use. Note: this also requires you to mark each of the constructor's parameters with @JsonProperty

You [should use the @JsonCreator annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#annotations-using-custom-constructor) when you want Jackson to constructor objects with a constructor or factory method as opposed letting Jackson use setters or public (non-final) fields

Additionally, your test will not pass until you override "equals" for both Person and Address

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Optional<Address> address;
    private Optional<String> phone;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this(firstName, lastName, age, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(
            @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
            @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
            @JsonProperty("age") int age,
            @JsonProperty("address") Optional<Address> address,
            @JsonProperty("phone") Optional<String> phone) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
```

Update: [Pull Request](https://github.com/101bits/java8-optional-json/pull/1) with passing tests

Comment: Can you explain what this will do differently, considering their edit?

Comment: An alternative to the `@JsonProperty` parameters is to use the [parameter names module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-parameter-names).

Comment: I didn't know about the parameter names module, thanks @shmosel

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added code examples and documentation links

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, `@JsonCreator` is not _strictly_ necessary here. As long as there is a parameterless constructor and _proper_ property descriptors, this will work.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good to know that json creator is not strictly necessary. I'm going to keep the answer as is because `@JsonCreator` is consistent with Jackson documentation and it communicates intent

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have read optional does not get serialized and hence, while deserializing you wont get the value if you are using default java serialization. However, if you are using your serialization, it should be fine.

Refer this link for more details:
[Why java.util.Optional is not Serializable, how to serialize the object with such fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc)