# How to map an OptionalLong to an Optional<Long>?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an instance of  `OptionalLong`. But one of my libraries requires an `Optional<Long>` as a parameter.

How can I convert my `OptionalLong` into an `Optional<Long>`?

I was dreaming about something like this:

```
OptionalLong secondScreenHeight = OptionalLong.of(32l); // or: OptionalLong.empty()
api.setHeight(secondScreenHeight.mapToRegularOptional()); // .mapToRegularOptional does not exist
```

Comment: There are many variations, but most of them leverage `OptionalLong.isPresent()` to distinguish between the empty and non-empty cases.

Comment: the question is why doesn't `OptionalLong` have no `map/filter` etc

Comment: `api.setHeight(…)` should not expect an `Optional<Long>` as argument type. Then you will not have such problems.

Comment: @Holger In some cases it cannot easily be avoided (i.e. if `Long` is the value of a type argument of a generic method)

Comment: Just don’t use `Optional` as parameter at all, whether generic or not. It's horrible to read. What does it mean to call `setHeight` with an empty optional argument? Do nothing? Then, don’t call it at all. `secondScreenHeight.ifPresent(api::setHeight)` makes much more sense.

Comment: To add to what Holger already pointed out, this is what IntelliJ would suggest you as well... *...Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result". Using a field with type java.util.Optional is also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, [which java.util.Optional is not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc)*

Comment: Why a bounty is opened here? The question received good answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know simpler solutions but this will do what you need.

```
OptionalLong secondScreenHeight = OptionalLong.of(32l);
Optional<Long> optional = secondScreenHeight.isPresent() 
    ? Optional.of(secondSceenHeight.getAsLong()) 
    : Optional.empty();
api.setHeight(optional);
```

Comment: I like about this solution, that it is readable and that the intent to remap the optional is clearly visible.

Answer (score 14):

You could do this:

```
final OptionalLong optionalLong = OptionalLong.of(5);

final Optional<Long> optional = Optional.of(optionalLong)
            .filter(OptionalLong::isPresent)
            .map(OptionalLong::getAsLong);
```

Comment: What I like about this solution is, that the initial variable is only used once. This makes it possible to create "long chains" in my code - I do not necessarily store the value in a variable.

Comment: I like that it does not use old `if else` syntax, but only shiny new java-8 syntax!

Comment: @slartidan well, still `if/else` inside filter and map though

Answer (score 5):

One more possibility, though only from JDK 9 is via the new `OptionalLong.stream()` method, which returns a `LongStream`.  This can then be boxed to a `Stream<Long>`:

```
OptionalLong optionalLong = OptionalLong.of(32);
Optional<Long> optional = optionalLong.stream().boxed().findFirst();
```

With JDK 8 something similar can be done, by stepping out to the [Streams](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.OptionalLong-) utility class in Guava:

```
Optional<Long> optional = Streams.stream(optionalLong).boxed().findFirst();
```

Comment: Also, `findAny` is 2 characters shorter.

Comment: I like about it, that it is short and does not rely on `isPresent`. However the intention is not as clearly visible as in some of the other answers. Thanks for sharing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Optional<Long> returnValue = Optional.empty();
if(secondScreenHeight.isPresent()) {
      returnValue = Optional.of(secondScreenHeight.getAsLong());
}
```