# Optional<List> Java 8 lambda expressions get first element

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I am newbie here and trying my way hard through java 8 streams + lambda. Can someone help me with the below piece of code? Need to find the age of first person from the list which is optional. This list could be null.

Missing from the code - null check for the first element of the list. Would like to have this check as well.

Something equivalent to below piece of code.

```
//input parameter 
//Optional<List<Person>> persons
public Integer getAgeOfFirstPerson(Optional<List<Person>> persons) {
    if (!persons.isPresent()) {
        return null;
    }

    Integer age = persons.get()
        .get(0)
        .getAge();

    return age;
}

//Person.java
class Person {
    Integer age;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I quote, don't use [`Optional` as args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823194/how-to-map-an-optionallong-to-an-optionallong#comment90601909_51823194)

Comment: Thanks for the note :)

Comment: Maybe more debatable, but you should probably avoid `Optional<List<?>>` the same way you should avoid `null` `List` variables: is there really a difference between an empty `Optional<List<?>>` and a non-empty one containing an empty `List`? If not, don't use `Optional` at all, use the empty `List` instead. If yes, maybe you should define your own type to clearly describe it.

Comment: @DidierL I disagree with the "if yes" part: `Optional<List<?>>` already describes it perfectly clearly. OTOH, I was never convinced by the arguments referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564612/9204 :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov what does “`Optional<List<?>>`” describe? Is there a semantic difference between an absent list and an empty list?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming the `List` inside your `Optional` can be empty, then you should account for this case as well. The easiest would thus be:

```
return persons.flatMap(list -> list.stream().findFirst()).map(Person::getAge).orElse(null);
```

This unfortunately does not handle a `null` first list entry as `findFirst()` throws a `NullPointerException` when the first element of a `Stream` is `null` (as Holger noted in the comments).

So if you want to skip `null` list entries and take the first non-null one, do as follows:

```
return persons.flatMap(list -> list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())
              .map(Person::getAge)
              .orElse(null);
```

Otherwise, if instead you always want the first entry even when it is `null`, you could adapt it like this:

```
return persons.flatMap(list -> list.stream().limit(1).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())
              .map(Person::getAge)
              .orElse(null);
```

however this really becomes quite convoluted, so it is simpler to just get back to testing whether the list is empty:

```
return persons.filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
              .map(list -> list.get(0))
              .map(Person::getAge)
              .orElse(null);
```

Comment: @Holger, I had forgotten that. I think there as well the recommendation was to avoid `null` items in streams. Anyway, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that can be generalized to any kind of data structure with a variable number of elements, including possibly zero. Such a structure should never be `null` and never contain `null`, as you can express the same by not having these elements or even no elements at all, in most use cases. So for the `List` parameter of this question, it should not be `Optional` in the first place, as the list can be empty instead of absent.

Comment: @Holger, I can't agree more with you 

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Optional.map`

```
public int getAgeOfFirstPerson(Optional<List<Person>> persons){ 
    return persons.map(people -> people.get(0).getAge()).orElse(0);
}
```

Do note, primitives do not have `null`(they are not objects), hence have replaced that with `0`.

Or further improved as [answered by @Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972741/1746118), if need be to check for Person being null as well.

Answer (score 1):

`return null` won't compile if `int` is the return type. Assuming you want an absent `Optional<Integer>` instead,

```
return persons.map(list -> list.get(0)).map(Person::getAge)
```

will work (unfortunately, there's no `mapToInt` returning `OptionalInt` like for streams). Two `map`s are needed to handle

> Missing from the code - null check for the first element of the list. Would like to have this check as well.

Comment: Edited the code. I would prefer returning Integer instead.

Comment: Then just add `.orElse(null)` at the end. Though as DidierL points out, this misses the "list is empty" case.

Comment: list -> list.get(0) will throw an index out of bound exception if the list is empty :(

Comment: @shakeel See the last version in Didier's answer instead.