# How to Deserialize json for class having Optional fields using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, option-type

I'm using `Jackson` to deserialise a class which has `Optional` member variables, so it looks like

```
class Test{
   Optional<String> testString;
}
```

but in serialised form it looks like, which is legit

```
{
"value": {
"testString": "hi"
}
```

How can I deserialise it back to my `Test` class?, because when I try to do so it says unknown field "value". Can it be possible without changing my test class.

Comment: Possibly related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673) and to understand better why `Optional` as a field type should not be preferred.

Comment: @nullpointer, its valid but the class which iam using is from third party lib

Answer (score 2):

You need to register `Jdk8Module`. Belowe you can find example, how to do that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setTestString(Optional.of("str"));

        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(test);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Test.class));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "testString" : "str"
}
Test{testString=Optional[str]}
```

See also:

1. [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)

Comment: in your case you are creating a new object but in my case i am try to deserialize
the json  
{
"value": {
"testString": "hi"
}, which is being read from file.

Comment: When you will enable `Jdk8Module` and serialise your `Test` object it will be look like in my example. So, deserialisation will start working without any changes. If you want to keep old version of `JSON` with `value` in root object you need to update `POJO`s structure. Can you change `JSON`? If yes, regenerate it with `Jdk8Module`. If no, you need to change `POJO` structure. Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Do you use `FasterXML` or `codehaus`?

Comment: @SiddharthThakrey, have you fixed your problem?

Comment: in my case the api is serializing response without using Jdk8Module which looks like 
{ "present": true
 "value"{
"testString":  "abc"
}}
 and iam trying to deserialize this above form of TestClass which looks like , cause that's third party api response

Comment: @SiddharthThakrey, when I try to serialise `private Optional<String> testString = Optional.of("Test")` the result is: `{"testString":{"present":true}}` Do you use any custom serialiser? That's strange that `testString` is inside `value` in your case. It should be something like: `{"testString": {"present": true,"value": "abc"}}`. In your case it is not possible to match `JSON` property with `Test`'s class `testString` property.

Comment: you are correct. yeah i mean i am getting in {"testString": {"present": true,"value": "abc"}} as the serialised form, my bad but still it is failing in deserialisation .

Comment: @SiddharthThakrey, in that case you need to implement custom deserializer.