# How can I use properly Optional with a `@RequestBody`?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, option-type

I use the Spring Boot 2.0.8.RELEASE.

I have a `@RestController` method looks like this:

```java
    @PostMapping("/message")
    public PushMessageResponse sendPush(@Validated @RequestBody PushMessageRequest pushMessageRequest) {
        final List<String> sentMessage = pushService.sendMessage(pushMessageRequest);

        return new PushMessageResponse(sentMessage);
    }
```

And I have a `PushMessageRequest` class that looks like this:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PushMessageRequest {

    private final Optional<UUID> clientId;
    private final Optional<String> token;
    private final Optional<String> text;
    private final Optional<PushOptions> pushOptions;
    @NotBlank
    private final String appName;

}
```

And If I send a request to this method with a body that doesn't contain some property I see that that kind of property(those that I didn't pass in the JSON request) is **null**.

I've already tried to add such configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Module jdk8Module() {
        return new Jdk8Module();
    }
}
```

I have expected to see that the Optional property of my DTO isn't **null** but such property has a value of `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: Never use `Optional` for field declarations. What you are doing is wrong in the first place.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala why so? These fields could be null, I want to force developers to check such fields for nullability.

Comment: you can use normal field and make you getter return Optional

Comment: you can do something like this: public class PushMessageRequest {

    private final UUID clientId;

    public Optional<UUID> getClientId(){
        Optional.ofNullable(clientId);
    }

}

Comment: @AmanGarg sure, I do this as a workaround. But I think there is a deserialization problem in the Spring MVC because `@RequestParam` works with Optional as expected. Or I didn't configure Spring properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @cameron1024, @AmanGarg, @RavindraRanwala I shouldn't use Optional as a field, because it is not intended to.

I choose the solution of creating methods that return `Optional#ofNullable()` of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use `Optional` here. You can simply use regular classes, and use `Optional.ofNullable()` to create `Optional` objects inside your controller class.

The `Optional` API was primarily intended to be used for methods that return a value that may be null, rather than transmitting data. For example, you can write your message class as:

```
public class PushMessageRequest {
    private UUID clientId;
    ...
}
```

and in your controller class, you can call:

```
@PostMapping("/message")
public PushMessageResponse sendPush(@Validated @RequestBody PushMessageRequest pushMessageRequest) {
    Optional<UUID> uuidOptional = Optional.ofNullable(pushMessageRequest.getUUID());
    ...
}
```

For a more detailed explanation of why you should not use `Optional` in a class that is serialized, refer to: [Why java.util.Optional is not Serializable, how to serialize the object with such fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc). Although this refers specifically to standard Java serialization, the reasoning applies to JSON serialization as well.

Comment: I want to use Optional in the fields because I want to implicitly force developers to check that field for nullability.

Comment: This doesn't force them to check for null. A lazy developer using optionals will simply call `optional.get()`. A lazy developer using regular classes will just call it without checking null.

Comment: This is a misuse of the API, and you should change them to regular fields

Comment: public class PushMessageRequest {

    private final UUID clientId;

    public Optional<UUID> getClientId(){
        Optional.ofNullable(clientId);
    }

}

Comment: @cameron1024 Sure, a lazy developer can do this, but this code doesn't pass a review.

Comment: Perhaps Brian Goetz's (Java language designer) opinion may help you see this more clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555

Comment: @cameron1024 Yes, sounds that I misuse Optional.