# Correctly deserialize Optional Optional Type

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, option-type

I have the following class:

```
class X(
    val x: Optional<Optional<Int>>
)
```

I can serialize it using the following mapper:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(Jdk8Module())
```

to this:

```
mapper.valueToTree(X(Optional.of(Optional.of(1)))) // -> {"x":1}
mapper.valueToTree(X(Optional.of(Optional.empty()))) // -> {"x":null}
mapper.valueToTree(X(Optional.empty())) // -> {}
```

But sadly, it does not work the reverse way:

```
{"x":1} -> X(Optional.of(Optional.of(1)))
{"x":null} -> X(Optional.of(Optional.empty())
{} -> X(Optional.empty())
```

Specifically, I want `{"x":null}` to deserialize as `X(Optional.of(Optional.empty())`
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: are you aware that Optional isn't supposed to be (de)serializable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc

Comment: https://blog.codefx.org/java/serialize-optional/ it seems to be possible though

Comment: Why have you got that? `Optional`, at least in Java, is for return values from methods, not for fields. And I am completely missing the point in using `Optional<Optional<Something>>` for anything at all.

Comment: Did you try writing your own serializer?