# Interface in generic type Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-8

Today I found strange code into jdk8 sources and couldn't find any explanation.

```
 static final Comparator<ChronoLocalDate> DATE_ORDER =
    (Comparator<ChronoLocalDate> & Serializable) (date1, date2) -> {
        return Long.compare(date1.toEpochDay(), date2.toEpochDay());
    };
```

Can anyone explain me why & `Serializable` out of `<>` ? 
And it would be great to provide link on documentation.

Link to source: [AbstractChronology](http://sabaka.github.io/jdk/xref/java/time/chrono/AbstractChronology.html#132)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda : it is an intersection cast.

Comment: It’s worth noting that it is strongly discouraged to use serializable lambdas as the serialized form highly depends on the binary form of the containing class and even compiling with a different compiler (or a different version of it) might break compatibility. Especially in the example of this question, `DATE_ORDER` seems to be intended to be a singleton, a property the (de-)serialized lambda will not preserve.

Answer (score 3):

`&` in that context indicates an intersection of types. Say you have classes like these:

```
interface SomeInterface
{
  public boolean isOkay();
}

enum EnumOne implements SomeInterface { ... }

enum EnumTwo implements SomeInterface { ... }
```

You want to be able to use any enum that implements SomeInterface as a type parameter in a generic type. Of course, you want to be able to use methods on both Enum and SomeInterface, such as `compareTo` and `isOkay`, respectively. Here's how that could be done:

```
class SomeContainer<E extends Enum<E> & SomeInterface>
{
  SomeContainer(E e1, E e2)
  {
    boolean okay = e1.isOkay() && e2.isOkay();
    if (e1.compareTo(e2) != 0) { ... }
  }
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.9

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question:

> what is `& Serializable`?

It's a intersection of types - the type must be *both* `Comparator<ChronoLocalDate>` *and* `Serializable`

> why is it not in angle brackets `< >`?

Because its a cast, not a generic parameter type