# Serialization of a lambda after its creation

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, java-8

I can [serialize a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda) with the following syntax:

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable) () -> System.out.println("");
try (ObjectOutput oo = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())) {
  oo.writeObject(r);
}
```

However if I receive the lambda from a client code and it has not been cast appropriately, I can't serialize it.

**How can I serialize `r` below without changing its definition:**

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("");
```

---

I have tried to serialize a "derived" object:

```
Runnable r1 = (Runnable & Serializable) r::run;
Runnable r2 = (Runnable & Serializable) () -> r.run();
```

but in each case, `oo.writeObject(rxxx);` fails with a `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: I don't believe this to be possible.

Comment: Strangely, it seems to work if you assign r to a static Runnable field first.

Comment: @Sean Van Gorder: it “works” if `r` is a `static` field because the `static` field is not stored on Serialization which means that on Deserialization you will get a lambda which will just access `r`, regardless of what value it has then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is correct, and by design.  Just as you cannot take a non-serializable object and make it serializable after instantiation, once a lambda is created, its serializability is set.

A lambda is serializable if its target type is serializable (and its captured arguments are serializable.)  Your first example is serializable because the target type is the intersection (Runnable & Serializable).  Your two attempts to convert `r` fail because in both cases, `r` is a captured variable that is not serializable, and so the resulting lambda expression / method reference is not serializable.  (The receiver for a bound method reference acts as a captured variable.)

Comment: What I really wish is the opposite, a way to opt out Serialization support if the target interface happened to inherit `Serializable` but I don’t want to support it for my lambda expression…

Comment: @Holger That's easy too; just provide a cast that does not include `Serializable`.  The cast is not magic; it is a more explicit, expression-friendly way to provide a target type.  And, if you've already got a serializable lambda and want to un-serializable it, you can use the tricks that assylias tried -- they'll effectively "wash off" the serializable marker.

Comment: if the target type already is `Serializable`, how can you “wash off” the serializable marker? Every re-wrapping in another lambda will again create a `Serializable` lambda, unless I use a different target type. But if I was able to use a different target type, I hadn’t the problem in the first place. I could forcibly add a captured non-`Serializable` value, but that still must be done very carefully to prevent attacks with a carefully designed serialized form. And it doesn’t allow to get rid of the overhead of the serializable lambda.

Comment: @Holger: You've asked enough that its an actual question now, far too much to fit in a comment ... :)