# How to get lambda (Function instance) captured value in runtime?

Tags: java, function, serialization, lambda, capture

Imagine we have some third party class that we can't change.
That class has a **java.lang.Function** field, setter and getter.
Setter accepts not a Function, but only a one function argument, and initializes function field via lambda.

```
    private class ThirdPartyClass {
        private Function<Integer, Integer> func;

        public void setFunc(Integer i2) {
            this.func = i1 -> i1 + i2;
        }

        public Function<Integer, Integer> getFunc() {
            return func;
        }
    }
```

In my code, I am using setter first and then getter to obtain a Function.

```
        //on application startup
        thirdPartyClass.setFunc(100);
        
        // after a while in the other module
        Function<Integer, Integer> func = thirdPartyClass.getFunc();
```

This is a very simplified example. Actual third party code is [spring state machine library](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine), particularly [this method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/main/spring-statemachine-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/guard/Guards.java#L42) in the role of a setter, and [this getter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/main/spring-statemachine-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/transition/AbstractTransition.java#L122).

How can I get function parameter that was passed to setter having only the Function object itself ?
Is it even possible ?

I found some Function lambdas serialization tricks (via types intersection feature), that allows to obtain **java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda** instance, which has captured value in it, process is described in that question:  
[How to make function Serializable in generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734640/how-to-make-function-serializable-in-generic-way/49735016#49735016)

But seems it is not working in my case, because it works only if intersection is applied on lambda creation.
Process is described in that one
[Serialization of a lambda after its creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391656/serialization-of-a-lambda-after-its-creation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: What is your use case?  This sounds like an [XY  problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  The returned function is acting as a closure.  In effect, the passed argument(s) that are "embedded" in the returned function are out scope and as such they are not accessible.