# Determining return type via bitwise operation

Tags: java, generics

I was wandering throught java docs and suddenly found this code:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Can anyone explain what kind of magic is going on after the **return** statement? Okay, the result of the method is determined by lambda expression in combination with functional interface. But what is it written before that? Is it casting return type via bitwise operation? I don't get it. As far I know bitwise is applicable only with numbers. Where can I read about this case more specifically?

Comment: This is not "bitwise", you cannot apply `<<` or `|` to interfaces. By this you define type which implements multiple interfaces, i. e. has all methods of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 adds the ability to cast the lambda into an anonymous intersection. 
The return type is both a `Comparator<T>` and `Serializable`

Referenced from: [assylias's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22808112/2270271)

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

*NOTE:*
Java sometimes adds new syntactic meanings to operators in order to maintain backwards compatibility.