# Weirdness with Spark serialization

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, apache-spark

I've came accross a problem with Spark, using the `JavaPairRdd.repartitionAndrepartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` method. I've tried everything any reasonable person would have thought of. I finally written a small snippet simple enough to visualize the problem :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("I", "am", "totally", "baffled");
        final HashPartitioner partitioner = new HashPartitioner(2);

        doSomething(sc, list, partitioner, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        doSomething(sc, list, partitioner, Main::compareString);
        doSomething(sc, list, partitioner, new StringComparator());
        doSomething(sc, list, partitioner, new SerializableStringComparator());
        doSomething(sc, list, partitioner, (s1,s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.charAt(0),s2.charAt(0)));
    }

    public static <T> void doSomething(JavaSparkContext sc, List<T> list, Partitioner partitioner, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        try {
            sc.parallelize(list)
                .mapToPair(elt -> new Tuple2<>(elt,elt))
                .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner,comparator)
                .count();
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("failure");
        }
    }

    public static int compareString(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(s1.charAt(0),s2.charAt(0));
    }

    public static class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.compare(s1.charAt(0),s2.charAt(0));
        }
    }

    public static class SerializableStringComparator implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.compare(s1.charAt(0),s2.charAt(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from the Spark logging, it outputs :

```
success
failure
failure 
success
failure
```

The exception thrown in case of failure is always the same :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$ObjectStreamClassMethods$.getObjFieldValues$extension(SerializationDebugger.scala:240)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:150)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:58)
org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:39)
org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:835)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:778)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:781)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1362)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:847)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Now I've got my fix : declaring my custom comparator as `Serializable` (I checked in the standard library code, the string case insensitive comparator is declared as serializable so that makes sense).

But why ? Why should I not use lambdas here ? I would have expected the second and the last one to work properly since I only used static methods and classes.

What I find especially weird is that I have registered the classes I am trying to serialize to Kryo, and the class I did not register can be trivially serialized with their default associated serializer (Kryo associates `FieldSerializer` as the default one for most of the classes). However, Kryo registrator is never executed before the task fails being serialized.

Comment: The deal is either you write the serialization or let Spark do it for you. If you do it, then you need to implement Serializable.

Comment: Lambdas are not Serializable by default. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda

Comment: @ayanguha in my real world example, I'm using Kryo serialization and as I did not specify a serializer for `Comparator` I expected it to default on a `FieldSerializer`, which is fine since I have no fields !

Comment: @kostya I'm gonna test it shortly

Comment: The exception is thrown even before my Kryo registrator is executed... This makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was not clearly expliciting why I was so baffled (about Kryo registering code not being executed), so I edited it to reflect it.

I have figured out that Spark uses two different serializers :

- one for serializing the tasks from the master to the slaves, called `closureSerializer` in the code (see `SparkEnv.scala`). It can only be set to `JavaSerializer` at the date of my post.
- one for serializing the actual data that is processed, called `serializer` in the `SparkEnv`. This one can be set either to `JavaSerializer` or `KryoSerializer.

Registering a class to Kryo does not ensure you that it will always be serialized with Kryo, it depends on how you use it. As an example, the `DAGScheduler` only uses `closureSerializer` so no matter how you configure serialization, you will always need to make your objects Java-serializables if they are manipulated by `DAGScheduler` at some point (unless Spark enables Kryo serialization for closures in later releases).