# Merging two List of objects in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Java class `Parent` with 20 attributes `(attrib1, attrib2 .. attrib20)` and its corresponding getters and setters. Also I have two lists of `Parent` objects: `list1` and `list2`.

Now I want to merge both lists and avoid duplicate objects based on `attrib1` and `attrib2`.

Using Java 8:

```
List<Parent> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But in which place I have to specify the attributes? Should I override `hashCode` and `equals` method?

Comment: Use Set to avoid duplicate values.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870136/java-lambda-stream-distinct-on-arbitrary-key/27872086

Comment: Cool echo feature you got there :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to implement `equals` and `hashCode`, the place to do it is *inside* the class `Parent`. Within that class add the methods like

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getAttrib1(), getAttrib2(), getAttrib3(),
            // …
                            getAttrib19(), getAttrib20());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this==obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Parent)) return false;
        Parent p=(Parent) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getAttrib1(), p.getAttrib1())
            && Objects.equals(getAttrib2(), p.getAttrib2())
            && Objects.equals(getAttrib3(), p.getAttrib3())
            // …
            && Objects.equals(getAttrib19(), p.getAttrib19())
            && Objects.equals(getAttrib20(), p.getAttrib20());
    }
```

If you did this, `distinct()` invoked on a `Stream<Parent>` will automatically do the right thing.

---

If you don’t want (or can’t) change the class `Parent`, there is no delegation mechanism for equality, but you may resort to *ordering* as that has a delegation mechanism:

```
Comparator<Parent> c=Comparator.comparing(Parent::getAttrib1)
        .thenComparing(Parent::getAttrib2)
        .thenComparing(Parent::getAttrib3)
        // …
        .thenComparing(Parent::getAttrib19)
        .thenComparing(Parent::getAttrib20);
```

This defines an order based on the properties. It requires that the types of the attributes itself are comparable. If you have such a definition, you can use it to implement the equivalent of a `distinct()`, based on that `Comparator`:

```
List<Parent> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .filter(new TreeSet<>(c)::add)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is also a thread-safe variant, in case you want to use it with parallel streams:

```
List<Parent> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .filter(new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(c)::add)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: wouldn't this create a new instance of TreeSet/ConcurrentSkipListSet for every element in the new list?

Comment: @VivekKothari no, it's a fundamental property of method references of the form `expression::name` that the expression is evaluated first and the result captured by the functional interface instance which will only invoke the method on that object. See, for example “[What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)” Or [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37979731/2711488) or [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30514995/2711488)

Answer (score 1):

Override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Parent` class to avoid duplicates from the lists. This will give you the exact result what you want.

Comment: That is bad advice. Never override `equals` without also overriding `hashCode`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java just read this and got to know why,,,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
public class Parent {

    public int no;
    public String name;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (no << 4) ^ name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Parent))
            return false;
        Parent o = (Parent)obj;
        return this.no == o.no && this.name.equals(o.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override `.equals(…)` and `.hashCode()`, you need to do so on the `Parent` class. Note that this may cause other uses of `Parent` to fail. Alexis C.'s linked solution is more conservative.