# Why do equivalent lambda expression and method reference behave differently when capturing static field value?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I'm a little bit confused about Java lambdas and method references behaviour. For ex., we have this code:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {

    private static StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("1");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String> consumer = s -> sBuilder.append(s);
        sBuilder = new StringBuilder("2");
        consumer.accept("3");
        System.out.println(sBuilder);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
23
```

This works as expected, but if we replace

**s -> sBuilder.append(s)**

with

**sBuilder::append**

the output will be:

```
2
```

Have you any ideas how to explain this? This isn't the same things? Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514995/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lambda-and-a-method-reference-at-a-runtime-leve) too convoluted for a duplicate?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a little bit :) thank you for useful references and answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the lambda expression, the `sBuilder` field is captured, but not evaluated. It will only be evaluated when the corresponding function interface method is invoked. At that point, the `sBuilder` references the new instance created and assigned to the field with

```
sBuilder = new StringBuilder("2");
```

In the method reference, the `sBuilder` field is evaluated immediately to produce a `Consumer` instance. That value references the instance created in the static initializer

```
private static StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("1");
```

and the `Consumer` will operate on that one. You print the new one.

---

From the Java Language Specification, concerning the [Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3)

> The body of an invocation method depends on the form of the method
>   reference expression, as follows:
>
> If the form is `ExpressionName :: [TypeArguments] Identifier` or
>   `Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the body of the
>   invocation method has the effect of a method invocation expression for
>   a compile-time declaration which is the compile-time declaration of
>   the method reference expression. Run-time evaluation of the method
>   invocation expression is as specified in §15.12.4.3, §15.12.4.4, and
>   §15.12.4.5, where:
>
> - The invocation mode is derived from the compile-time declaration as specified in §15.12.3.
> - **The target reference is the value of `ExpressionName` or `Primary`, as determined when the method reference expression was
>     evaluated.**
> - The arguments to the method invocation expression are the formal parameters of the invocation method.

Comment: In other words, `s -> sBuilder.append(s)` is equivalent to `s -> Main.sBuilder.append(s)`, while `sBuilder::append` is equivalent to `StringBuilder temp = Main.sBuilder; s -> temp.append(s)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why mark it as community wiki at first?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Because I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate out there but I couldn't find it. I don't care about the points. It feels wrong when I know there's more information elsewhere.