# How to combine two lists without using foreach?

Tags: java, list, collections

**Originally, I have this code:**

```
String[] A;
String[] B;
//...
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>(A.length + B.length);
for (int i= 0; i< B.length; i++){
   myList.add(A[i]);
   myList.add("*".equals(B[i]) ? B[i] : doSomethingWith(B[i]));
}
```

How to refactor if using, preferably, Java 8?

If for instance I have these arrays

**A = {"one", "two", "three", "four"}**

**B = {"five", "six", "seven", "eight"}**

At the end of the code, myList will be:

**myList = {"one", "five", "two", "six", "three", "seven", "four", "eight"}**

Comment: Why without using foreach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866753/merging-two-list-of-objects-in-java-8

Comment: @hellzone SonarQube issues

Comment: should duplicate entries also be duplicate in the list?

Comment: I wouldn't say this needs refactoring - it's already clear what it does, and trying to wrap it in some sort of stream will likely just make it harder to follow.

Comment: @LucasCarnevalli It's not a concat. The order has to remain as it is

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two List of objects in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866753/merging-two-list-of-objects-in-java-8)

Comment: would a `while` loop work?

Comment: @vts Link's already been mentioned and it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @akshayapandey for each is not wanted

Comment: @raullalves btw, you are not using an actual `foreach` loop right now

Comment: Maybe using two iterators instead of looping the indices? But I really don't see a problem with the code as it is. If SonarQube complains, just tell it to ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally don't think this needs refactoring as any "streamed" code will be less readable and less intuitive than your existing code, but as a pure proof-of-concept:

```
String[] A;
String[] B;
List<String> myList;

myList = IntStream.range(0, B.length)
                  .mapToObj(i -> new String[]
                      {
                          A[i],
                          "*".equals(B[i]) ? B[i] : doSomethingWith(B[i])
                      })
                  .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/qYD56q).

---

- We use `IntStream.range` to provide the indices into our arrays.
- `mapToObj` maps each index to an array containing the elements we want (this stage is also needed as `IntStream::flatMap` can only convert to another `IntStream`, we want to convert it to a `Stream` of `String`s).
- `flatMap` maps each array to a stream, then "flattens" the resulting stream of streams.
- Finally, we just `collect` the results.

Comment: Indeed, personally I cannot see the obsession with needing a streams / Java 8 solution for everything when it just makes the code less readable (in my opinion).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: you could improve readability - I had a little go, but it got rejected; benefits of streaming are however beyond readability. OPs solution has to do 'full array scan' while streamed solution can be lazily evaluated, elements can be skipped (and computation e.g. `doSomethingWith` will not happen on skipped ones), finally it all can be parallelised, which would be much harder in OPs case and would result in shared, possibly contested memory access

Comment: @diginoise I tried to deliberately mimic parts of the OP's structure - I appreciate the edit with `Arrays::stream`, though.

Comment: There is no sense in initializing `myList` with `new ArrayList<>(A.length + B.length)`; it will be overwritten with the unrelated result of the stream operation anyway. Further you can simplify this to `.mapToObj(i -> Stream.of(A[i], "*".equals(B[i])? B[i]: doSomethingWith(B[i])) .flatMap(Function.identity())`

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
 String[] A;
 String[] B;
 //...
 List<String> myList= Arrays.asList (A);
 List<String> myList2 = Arrays.stream(B).map(
    (x)->"*".equals(x) ? x : doSomethingWith(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
 myList.addAll(myList2);
```