# How does invokedynamic instruction decide its description?

Tags: jvm, bytecode

I'm using ASM to modify method reference, so what i can hook it. My method is modify the bootstrap's `Handle` arg, and make it target to a new method which i will generate it later. The follow is my code snippet for this goal.

```java
class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodNode{

    //...

    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        super.visitEnd();
        ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> iterator = this.instructions.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            AbstractInsnNode node = iterator.next();
            if (node instanceof InvokeDynamicInsnNode) {
                InvokeDynamicInsnNode tmpNode = (InvokeDynamicInsnNode) node;
                String samName = tmpNode.name;

                String middleMethodName = samName + "sa" + counter.incrementAndGet();
                String middleMethodDesc = "";

                Handle handle = (Handle) tmpNode.bsmArgs[1];

                Type type = (Type) tmpNode.bsmArgs[2];
                //handleNew will reference to the middleMethod
                Handle handleNew = new Handle(Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC, "cn/curious/asm/lambda/LambdaModel", middleMethodName,
                        type.getDescriptor(), false);
                tmpNode.bsmArgs[1] = handleNew;
                middleMethodDesc = type.getDescriptor();
                String dynamicNewDesc = "()" + Type.getReturnType(tmpNode.desc);

                InvokeDynamicInsnNode newDynamicNode =
                        new InvokeDynamicInsnNode(tmpNode.name,
                                dynamicNewDesc,
                                tmpNode.bsm, tmpNode.bsmArgs[0], handleNew, type);
                //Here, i remote the origin InvokeDynamicInsnNode and add mine
                iterator.remove();
                iterator.add(newDynamicNode);

                MethodNode methodNode = new MethodNode(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC ,
                        middleMethodName,middleMethodDesc,null,null);
                methodNode.visitEnd();
                syntheticMethodList.add(methodNode);
            }
        }
        accept(mv);
    }

   //...
}
```

And my test java source code is as follows:

```java
public class LambdaModel {

    public void test1() {
        Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
        consumer.accept("hello world");
    }

    public void test2() {
        Consumer<String> consumer = s -> System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaModel model = new LambdaModel();
        model.test1();
    }
}
```

And, the generated class file is as follows:

```java
public class LambdaModel {
    public LambdaModel() {
    }

    public void test1() {
        System.out.getClass();
        Consumer<String> consumer = LambdaModel::acceptsa1;
        consumer.accept("hello world");
    }

    public void test2() {
        Consumer<String> consumer = (s) -> {
            System.out.println(s);
        };
    }

    public static void lambda$accept(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaModel model = new LambdaModel();
        model.test1();
    }
    //This method is generated by using ASM
    public static void acceptsa1(String var0) {
    }
}
```

You can see that, the `acceptsa1` method hasn't code body, because i don't know how to analyze the corresponding bytecode.

Follow is the source code's bytecode snippet, and my question is inside.

```java
public test1()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    DUP
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Object.getClass ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    POP

    INVOKEDYNAMIC accept(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)Ljava/util/function/Consumer; [
      // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
      java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
      // arguments:
      (Ljava/lang/Object;)V, 
      // handle kind 0x5 : INVOKEVIRTUAL
      java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V, 
      (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ]
    ASTORE 1
   L1
```

**Q1: I can't understand the follow instructions with the rear invokeydynamic instruction.**

```
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    DUP
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Object.getClass ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    POP
```

**Q2: Why the invokedynamic's description has a PrintStream parameter? What's rules it based.**

```
INVOKEDYNAMIC accept(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)Ljava/util/function/Consumer;
```

I am sorry i can't describe the questions exactly. Maybe my final question is how the `invokedynamic` instruction works in bytecode.

---

**Update**
I find an important point that change a method reference to a normal lambda expression. When you generate the middle method name, you must set the access of this method to **ACC_SYNTHETIC**, then you can get your wanted.
e.g.,
Method Reference:

```java
MethodReferenceMain referenceMain = new MethodReferenceMain();
Comparator<User> comparator2 = referenceMain::compareByName;
```

Generated Class:

```java
MethodReferenceMain referenceMain = new MethodReferenceMain();
Comparator<User> comparator2 = (var1, var2) -> {
     return referenceMain.compareByName(var1, var2);
};
```

**Note**: There must have more problem that i have not meet. But that's a great step for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `invokedynamic` instruction does not mandate any signature. It’s the code generator which decides for a particular signature and bootstrap method to use, which together define the actual semantic.

E.g., the signature and its meaning is entirely different when using  [`StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html#makeConcat(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup,java.lang.String,java.lang.invoke.MethodType)) instead of [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup,java.lang.String,java.lang.invoke.MethodType,java.lang.invoke.MethodType,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle,java.lang.invoke.MethodType)) as bootstrap method.

The documentation of these methods and their containing classes describes the behavior thoroughly. But before digging into the bytecode details you should first understand the source code features, i.e. of capturing method references, as explained in [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488). The method reference `System.out::println` captures the `PrintStream` found in the static field `System.out` when instantiating the `Consumer`. Hence, the generated factory method consumes a `PrintStream` and produces a `Consumer`, resulting in the signature `(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)Ljava/util/function/Consumer;`.

So, before executing the `invokedynamic` instruction, the field has to be read with a `GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out` instruction. The `DUP; INVOKEVIRTUAL getClass()` sequence is part of an intrinsic `null` check which has been discussed in [In Java Lambda's why is getClass() called on a captured variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43115645/2711488)

Comment: Can i modify a method reference to be a normal lambda by ASM?
e.g., change `Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;` to `Consumer<String> consumer = (str)->System.out.println(str);`

Comment: A lambda expression gets compiled to a synthetic method holding the body of the lambda expression, then, the instance of the functional interface is generated like a method reference to that synthetic method. To perform the equivalent on the bytecode level, you need to create the method. Like the `lambda$accept` method you’ve already posted.