# Why does javac insert Objects.requireNonNull(this) for final fields?

Tags: java, java-8, javac, java-11, ecj

Consider the following class:

```
class Temp {
    private final int field = 5;

    int sum() {
        return 1 + this.field;
    }
}
```

Then I compile and decompile the class:

```
> javac --version
javac 11.0.5

> javac Temp.java

> javap -v Temp.class
  ...
  int sum();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: (0x0000)
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: aload_0
         2: invokestatic  #3   // Method java/util/Objects.requireNonNull:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
         5: pop
         6: iconst_5
         7: iadd
         8: ireturn
```

In simple words, `javac` compiles `sum()` to this:

```
int sum() {
    final int n = 1;
    Objects.requireNonNull(this); // <---
    return n + 5;
}
```

What is `Objects.requireNonNull(this)` doing here? What's the point? Is this somehow connected to reachability?

The Java 8 compiler is similar. It inserts `this.getClass()` instead of `Objects.requireNonNull(this)`:

```
int sum() {
    final int n = 1;
    this.getClass(); // <---
    return n + 5;
}
```

I also tried to compile it with Eclipse. It doesn't insert `requireNonNull`:

```
int sum() {
    return 1 + 5;
}
```

So this is javac-specific behavior.

Comment: Seems, it does not realize that this is unnecessary for `this`, compared to other expressions.

Comment: good catch(+1). to add to it, the same behavior can be observed with `javac 15-ea` as well. further observation, removing `final` works fine.

Comment: trying to fit in a comment, `int sum();...
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: aload_0
         2: invokestatic  #13    // Method java/util/Objects.requireNonNull:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
         5: pop
         6: iconst_5
         7: iadd
         8: ireturn` versus when removing the final keyword resolving to `int sum();...
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: aload_0
         2: getfield      #7                  // Field field:I
         5: iadd
         6: ireturn`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since the field is not only `final`, but a *compile-time constant*, it will not get accessed when being read, but the read gets replaced by the constant value itself, the `iconst_5` instruction in your case.

But the behavior of throwing a `NullPointerException` when dereferencing `null`, which would be implied when using a `getfield` instruction, must be retained¹. So when you change the method to

```
int sumA() {
  Temp t = this;
  return 1 + t.field;
}
```

Eclipse will insert an explicit null check too.

So what we see here, is `javac` failing to recognize that in this specific case, when the reference is `this`, the non-null property is guaranteed by the JVM and hence, the explicit null check is not necessary.

¹ see [JLS §15.11.1. Field Access Using a Primary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1-200-B):

> - If the field is not `static`:
>
>   - The *Primary* expression is evaluated. If evaluation of the *Primary* expression completes abruptly, the field access expression completes abruptly for the same reason.
>   - If the value of the *Primary* is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown.
>   - If the field is a non-blank `final`, then the result is the value of the named member field in type `T` found in the object referenced by the value of the *Primary*.
>
>   …

Comment: Good point. It's even easier to demonstrate like this: `Temp t = null; return 1 + t.field`. `Objects.requireNonNull(t)`, otherwise it would return 6 without NPE.

Comment: Is there not also the fact, that an other class could use use reflection to set the field to null at any point in time? (Final is a language construct, not a runtime constraint).

Comment: @MTilsted: No, because in this case the field itself is a primitive `int`, which cannot be null.

Comment: @MTilsted changing final fields with reflection can result in undefined behavior. Potentially not affecting inlined values is one of them.

Comment: @MTilsted the check is not about the field value. It is about the field owner reference, i.e. `this`. The reference cannot be changed via Reflection and it is impossible to be `null`, because it is impossible to enter an instance method with a `null` receiver reference; the invocation instruction would already fail.

Comment: There's a policy that `javac` doesn't do optimisation. It used to but made it more complicated and, I believe, hindered HotSpot. I think there was a JVM change that made `getClass` undesirable (I forget what), but it and `Objects.requireNonNull` are HotSpot intrinsics.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline the transition from using `getClass` to `requireNonNull` has been addressed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43115645/2711488).