# Source code of Spring Boot does not match the bytecode

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ issue tracker, [someone](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-333390/Download-sources-automatically-not-working-with-Maven#focus=Comments-27-8222767.0-0) noticed that IntelliJ indicates that the source code and the bytecode do not match for some classes of Spring Boot. Error message "Library source does not match the bytecode for class XYZ". The original assumption was that this is a bug of IntelliJ.

However, there are indeed differences between source code and bytecode.
Example: class JerseyAutoConfiguration, method addInitParameters in version 3.1.4

Source code:

```java
private void addInitParameters(DynamicRegistrationBean<?> registration) {
    this.jersey.getInit().forEach(registration::addInitParameter);
}
```

Decompiled code:

```java
private void addInitParameters(DynamicRegistrationBean<?> registration) {
    Map var10000 = this.jersey.getInit();
    Objects.requireNonNull(registration);
    var10000.forEach(registration::addInitParameter);
}
```

It looks like the compiler inserted an `Objects.requireNonNull(..)` for each method reference.

Is the difference an expected behavior for which I haven't found the documentation yet? Or should source code and bytecode match in Maven Central and the current behavior is not expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222479/whats-the-value-of-the-generated-getclass-invocation-for-method-references

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413106/java-lang-nullpointerexception-is-thrown-using-a-method-reference-but-not-a-lamb

From these 2 answers: JLS requires that method reference throws NPE if class is null (when method reference is created, not when its actually called), thus compiler creates a null check.