# How to define a function taking a Serializable lambda as parameter

Tags: java, serialization, lambda

Is it possible to declare a method taking a Serializable lambda as parameter without having to declare a dedicated interface or ask the client to [cast the lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda) ?

Lets use this toy example to illustrate my question:

```
 static <T, R> void serialize(Function<T, R> f) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())) {
      oos.writeObject(f);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    serialize(e -> e);
  }
```

Lambdas are not Serializable by default, and the expected `NotSerializableException` is thrown.

To make it work, we can cast the lambda to add an additional Serializable bound.

```
  static <T, R> void serialize(Function<T, R> f) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())) {
      oos.writeObject(f);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    serialize((Function<Object, Object> & Serializable) e -> e);
  }
```

However, this solution is unpleasant since it forces every caller to cast their lambda and the method signature does show that `f` must be serializable. It is verbose and error prone.

To remove the boilerplate and make it type safe, we can define a dedicated interface:

```
  interface SerFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R>, Serializable { }

  static <T, R> void serialize(SerFunction<T, R> f) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())) {
      oos.writeObject(f);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    serialize(e -> e);
  }
```

It does the job and almost suit my needs. The only drawback of this pattern is that I have to create a dedicated interface on top of each functional interface which is a bit cumbersome. Is it possible to get ride of the extra interface and declare the multiple bounds directly in the method signature ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but as it doesn't have an answer, I'll give it a try.

> However, this solution is unpleasant since it forces every caller to
>   cast their lambda and the method signature does show that f must be
>   serializable. It is verbose and error prone.

Even though this solution will still require you to state that your lambda expression also implements the Serializable interface, this does **require** you to do so.

So, it gives an error when it is not implemented.
It also allows children of Function to be used when they do not implement SerFunction.

```
public static <T, R, F extends Function<T, R> & Serializable> void serialize(F f) throws IOException
{
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))
    {
        oos.writeObject(f);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    serialize((Function<Object, Object> & Serializable) e -> e);
    // all happy

    serialize((Function<Object, Object>) e -> e);
    // compiler error "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Function<Object, Object> conforms to Serializable
    // inference variable F has incompatible bounds:
    // lower bounds: Function<Object, Object>
    // upper bounds: Function<T, R>, Serializable"

}
```

Comment: Would be better if the cast was implicit, of course, but still useful.