# Serializing a Predicate<T> in MapReduce

Tags: java, serialization, mapreduce, predicate

I am currently writing a RandomForest implementation in MapReduce and am trying to figure out how to go about serializing (implementing Writable) somehow on the Predicate interface. I have a class with a field that is of type Predicate. Any tips as to how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Where does your `Predicate` interface come from?  Is it `java.util.function.Predicate`?

Comment: Yes, and I did figure out how to serialize it using this link. Not using Writables though. [predicate serialization](http://www.coderanch.com/t/631879/java/java/Java-good-bad-ugly)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with similar ideas from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda)

If you have a predicate say;

```
final Predicate<CassandraRow> verifyPredicate = 
r -> Objects.equals(r.getObject("column_name"), Boolean.TRUE);
```

It can be converted into a serialisable Predicate as

```
final Predicate<CassandraRow> verifyPredicate = 
(Predicate<CassandraRow> & Serializable) r -> Objects.equals(r.getObject("column_name"), Boolean.TRUE);
```