# Automatically inferred multiply bounded type parameter - is it possible?

Tags: java

In the following code:

```
interface Callback {
    void greet(String greeting);
}

private static <T extends Callback & Serializable> void greetMe(T callback) {
    callback.greet("Hello world!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    greetMe(greeting -> System.out.println(greeting));
}
```

The following line does not compile, because the lambda is not *Serializable*:

```
greetMe(greeting -> System.out.println(greeting));
```

My question is, is there any syntactic sugar for making the lambda implement Serializable, or do I have to make it a non-anonymous class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely a duplicate, and the post helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JLS 15.16. Cast Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> Casts can be used to explicitly "tag" a lambda expression or a method reference expression with a particular target type. To provide an appropriate degree of flexibility, the target type may be a list of types denoting an intersection type, provided the intersection induces a functional interface (§9.8).

You can cast it directly to `Serializable`:

```
greetMe((Callback & Serializable) greeting -> System.out.println(greeting));
```

Comment: There are a lot of topics dealing with this subject, please flag as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: you are right... usually I do mark them or vote it to be a duplicate... it just happened that I had the answer already and so the further research of whether it was even asked was done after that... and all that just happened within 7 minutes ;-)