# Custom interface in Java Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a method from library, which look like this:

```
<T> T invoke(K key, EntryProcessor<K, V, T> entryProcessor, Object... arguments);
```

And `EntryProcessor` interface has a single method definition:

```
T process(MutableEntry<K, V> entry, Object... arguments) throws EntryProcessorException;
```

Unfortunately for my use case I need `EntryProcessor` with `Serializable`.

One solution is to make a new class implementing both `EntryProcessor` and `Serializable`, in that case I would have to create a different class for each different use case.

Normally, without `Serializable`, I can call `invoke` method as a lambda, which saves me from creating pack of specialized classes.

```
foo.invoke(1L, (entry, arguments) -> { 
    ...
    return null;
});
```

Is there a way to extend this lambda with `Serializable` interface?

Comment: See [How to serialize a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22807912/2711488)

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[0];
EntryProcessor<Long, String, Integer> it;

it = (EntryProcessor<Long, String, Integer> & Serializable) (entry, args) -> 1;

invoke(1L, it, arguments);
```

Comment: That helper method does not work. It returns a serializable object having a reference to the `original` object that is not serializable. So any attempt to serialize it will fail.

Comment: yeah. thanks sir. I'll remove it.