# Hibernate - can a Java8 Function Object be persisted in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lambda, java-8

I am working on an abstract model to represent a variety of complex business processes based on event registration. For that purpose, I want to be able to persist Java8 Function objects using the newest version of Hibernate, such as

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    private Runnable onUpdate = () -> System.out.println("worked");
    private java.util.function.Function<String, String> identity = s -> s;
    // imagine bean-compliant getter and setter
}
```

Persisting method references is not an option, since partial method application during runtime before setting a callback is a requirement.

Just trying above code leads to the following exception:
    `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.lang.Runnable ...`

Is there any way to persist function objects that match a fixed functional interface such as `Runnable`? And if not, what alternative strategies are available?

**EDIT concerning the XY-problem:**

I want to be able to associate methods in an object with some hibernate entity's
[PostUpdate callback](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/events/Events.html) during *runtime*, while letting the user supply all arguments which the hibernate callback can not supply. For example, I have an entity `@Entity public class Bar` and another controller class with a  method `void foo(Bar new, int i)`. Now, every time a specific instance of `Bar` is updated in the database, I want it to call `foo` with the updated object and a parameter `i`, which is specified by the user during current or some previous runtime while associating the `foo-Event` with the `Bar` instance.

Most importantly, I want to **persist** this runtime association using Hibernate, keeping a reference to the method, the object the method belongs to and all parameters supplied during association. Then, on server startup, as soon as the controller object is loaded it listens to changes made to the entity instance.

Comment: So you want to store the Java code of the functional interface in your DB? I doubt this is possible out-of-the-box. But you could implement your own abstraction for functions and serialize them.

Comment: What do you want to do with it after ? It seems to by a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: I want to register a set of process-specific callbacks with [hibernate events](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/events/Events.html) so that when an entity gets updated from somewhere, code is executed to automatically resolve invalid entity states

Comment: Maybe you can't (or wouldn't want want to) persist a `Function`, but you can certainly persist a `String` that could be mapped to a function.

Comment: Cant you persist its bytes via making it `Serializable`?

Comment: Persisting the binary representation of a function won't work, since memory addresses of external references in closures would not be the same after application restart.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while and I don't understand the requirements very exactly but it seems that hibernate-envers would be much better suited for this

Comment: @Eugene as far as I understand, Envers are used for versioning of field contents. I don't see how that is related

Comment: @Dracam as far as I understand u want simething to happen every time youy entity is "touched", that can be done with envers

Comment: Is it possible to assign behaviour at runtime though? For hard-coded behaviour I can use hibernate callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Unfortunately in current versions of Hibernate it is impossible to store Java 8 functions in a database. Lambdas do not implement `Serializable` and there is no way to make them do so.

Comment: So if I built a serializable class containing a reference to the callback origin, a method name and a map with fieldname -> value, I should be able to use that instead. Right?

Comment: That sounds about right. I can't confirm without doing the code myself, but that sounds like a reasonable strategy.

Comment: @JonathanCoustick you can make them serializable via `& Serializable` https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda&ved=0ahUKEwiO--S91_rXAhUJtBoKHXV8AOIQjjgIITAA&usg=AOvVaw00rojBF_0nCm07YqFf_TlJ

Comment: @Eugene I can't have `Runnable & Serializable` as a valid Type of a `callback` field in an entity. I could store a string and provide a setter, serializing the passed lambda, but I doubt that would work for non-pure functions or closures.

Comment: @Eugene apparently your solution causes the lambda to evaluate all references (such as an `AtomicInteger::get` in an outer scope) during serialization, thereby losing all closure capabilities. One could still make this work by supplying database IDs instead, but I think I'd prefer the serializable-class-solution. However, your idea is still worth an answer.

Comment: Is this `Serializable` thing `Hibernate` specific? I mean that that my Entities persist ok without implementing `Serializable` using OpenJPA.

Comment: @pirho Stored fields must be `Serializable`, `String`, a primitive, collection or made up of the above. See http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/persistable-basic-types/ for details.

Comment: @JonathanCoustick Thanks, seems that I mixed things a bit.