# Implementing the Comparator for JavaRDD.top with lambda throws exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to take the 25 top items of a `JavaPairRDD` like this:

```
JavaPairRDD rdd = ...;
List<Tuple2<String, Long>> top25 = rdd.top(25, (t1, t2) -> {
                                        if (!t1._2.equals(t2._2)) {
                                            return -1 * Long.compare(t1._2, t2._2);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            return t1._1.compareTo(t2._1);
                                        }
                                    })
```

This is sorting based on first the value and if values are equal, then on the keys. When I run it, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

I think the problem is that the inline lambda function playing the role of `Comparator` is not serializable.

I've got two questions. First, assuming my assumption is correct, why the `Comparator` needs to be serializable? And second, how to solve this problem?

Comment: What if the `Comparator` contains state. Should not it be serialized to preserve the state?

Comment: Personally, I have never faced a stateful comparator! I mean it is thinkable but not the everyday case. Usually, all a comparator needs to perform is the two items to compare.

Comment: Try to use custom comparator class that also implements `Serializable` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I was hoping I could implement it with just a lambda function!

Comment: Quick search leads to this very interesting lambda functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda