# Serializing and Deserializing Lambda with Jackson

Tags: json, serialization, lambda, java-8, jackson

I am trying to serialise and deserialise a class `RuleMessage` but can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
public class RuleMessage {
    private String id;
    private SerializableRunnable sRunnable;

    public RuleMessage(String id, SerializableRunnable sRunnable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sRunnable = sRunnable;
    }
}
```

```
public interface SerializableRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable {
}
```

```
    @Test
    public void testSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
        MAPPER.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, 
                                                               JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        
        SerializableRunnable r = () -> System.out.println("Serializable!");

        RuleMessage rule = new RuleMessage("1", r);
        System.out.println(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(businessRule));
}
```

I am using `Java 8`. Can someone tell me if this is possible in the `Jackson` library?

Comment: First thing, you can't pass a Runnable as parameter. You have use threads for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jackson` was created to keep object state not behaviour. This is why it tries to serialise `POJO`'s properties using `getters`, `setters`, etc. Serialising lambdas break this idea. Theres is no any property to serialise, only a method which should be invoked. Serialising raw lambda object is really bad idea and you should redesign your app to avoid uses cases like this.

In your case `SerializableRunnable` interface extends `java.io.Serializable` which gives one option - [Java Serialisation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization). Using `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` we can serialise lambda object to byte array and serialise it in `JSON` payload using `Base64` encoding. `Jackson` supports this scenario providing `writeBinary` and `getBinaryValue` methods.

Simple example could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class JsonLambdaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        SerializableRunnable action = () -> System.out.println("Serializable!");

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new RuleMessage("1", action));
        System.out.println(json);

        RuleMessage ruleMessage = mapper.readValue(json, RuleMessage.class);
        ruleMessage.getsRunnable().run();
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = LambdaJsonSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LambdaJsonDeserializer.class)
interface SerializableRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable {
}

class LambdaJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SerializableRunnable> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SerializableRunnable value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
            outputStream.writeObject(value);
            gen.writeBinary(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}

class LambdaJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SerializableRunnable> {
    @Override
    public SerializableRunnable deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        byte[] value = p.getBinaryValue();
        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);
             ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
            return (SerializableRunnable) inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}

class RuleMessage {
    private String id;
    private SerializableRunnable sRunnable;

    @JsonCreator
    public RuleMessage(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("sRunnable") SerializableRunnable sRunnable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sRunnable = sRunnable;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public SerializableRunnable getsRunnable() {
        return sRunnable;
    }
}
```

Above code prints `JSON`:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "sRunnable" : "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"
}
```

and lambda:

```
Serializable!
```

See also:

- [How to serialize a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda)
- [How to serialize a lambda function in Java?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-serialize-a-lambda-function-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First, in RuleMessage you have to either create getters / setters or make the fields public in order to provide Jackson access to the fields.

Your code then prints something like this:

```
{"@class":"RuleMessage","id":"1","sRunnable":{"@class":"RuleMessage$$Lambda$20/0x0000000800b91c40"}}
```

This JSON document cannot be deserialized because RuleMessage has no default constructor and the lambda cannot be constructed.

Instead of the lambda, you could create a class:

```
  public class Runner implements SerializableRunnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Serializable!");
    }
  }
```

and construct your pojo like this:

```
new RuleMessage("1", new Runner())
```

The Jackson deserializer is now able to reconstruct the objects and execute the runner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have a default constructor and getters/setters, I removed them for brevity(should have mentioned that).  I want to have a flexible design where I can wrap a method call in a lambda function and serialize it into the db. At a later time, I would like to deserialize the lambda and invoke it. I tried implementing the class within the function but Jackson cannot serialize that. It works fine if I move the class outside the function. Is there a way to serialize inner classes or lambda in Jackson?